# How to open Android App using Actions Builder?

Tags: android-studio, google-assistant-sdk, actions-builder

I want to open my Android App using the Actions Builder.

For example:
I tell Google Assistant to talk with my chatbot and then I tell to start the timer. My app should open in the timer screen.

I tried App Actions but that is not related to Actions Builder.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A conversational action built with Actions Builder may provide [a basic card](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-rich#basic_card) with a web URL you can intercept in your Android app using [a deep link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that and mark your answer as correct