# How to tell Google Assistant to automatically open Android App using Actions Builder or Actions SDK?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, actions-builder

Through conversations in google assistant I want to open my android app on my phone.

For example: I'm conversing with my chatbot and as a response to my query the bot should open my android app.

My requirement is to **open the app automatically** (user is not required to click on the deep link response to open the app)

I have looked at the documentation and references of Action Builder and Actions SDK. But couldn't find any proper solution on how to do it.

I have already looked at the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68808517/16853560) of another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68620044/how-to-open-android-app-using-actions-builder). However, that solution suggests user has to **manually click** on the deep-link in the conversation response to open the app which doesn't suit my needs. I want the app to be automatically opened without user intervention

Can anyone provide a code snippet (for webhook) or steps on how to do it?

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other response noted, there are no automatic ways to open an app in this way. What you may be able to do potentially is have your webhook [send a push notification to your mobile app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message), which will then [automatically open the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089963/how-to-automatically-open-the-app-without-user-action-on-receiving-a-push-on-and).

Comment: I used firebase cloud messaging service to achieve this. My android app listens to the messages in FirebaseMessagingService and my Webhook sends the notification message.