# Launch a URL from webhook Actions Google or DialogFlow in Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to launch a web url that will act as a deeplink for my app to launch it, it there a way to launch a URL in [DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/) or in [Actions Google](https://developers.google.com/assistant) using there fulfilment or the webhook for the Google Actions, I have created a [custom intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/custom-intents) and against that intent I like to launch specific feature of my app but it is not triggering the intent as it do in case of [Build In Intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents) so as an alternative if [Google Assistant](https://assistant.google.com/) launch that URL the purpose will be served.

I found some [code](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/interactivecanvas/build/action) that looks useful but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Below is the code

```
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
app.intent('welcome', (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Welcome! Do you want me to change color or pause spinning?');
    conv.ask(new HtmlResponse({
    url: 'https://your-web-app.com',
  }));
```

});

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell Google Assistant to automatically open Android App using Actions Builder or Actions SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110420/how-to-tell-google-assistant-to-automatically-open-android-app-using-actions-bui)

Comment: This is the same question as one asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110420/how-to-tell-google-assistant-to-automatically-open-android-app-using-actions-bui

Comment: So looks like there is no direct way to launch application against custom intents

Comment: Does answer provided in different thread by Nick is solution for your answer?

Comment: Nope, I am looking to open just as we do in built in intents

Comment: Could you provide scenario? You would provide in response with link or you want to open new url page using your app/browser with specific url?